# Why is my composer.json automatically deleted or missing after composer install?

Tags: php, composer-php

After `$ composer install`, everything went well but the `composer.json` was missing (deleted?).

This is, `composer.json` will no longer exist after `composer install`.

That is very strange.

---

Here is my `composer.json`:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "http://wpackagist.org"
    },
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "wordpress",
        "type": "webroot",
        "version": "4.4.1",
        "dist": {
          "type": "zip",
          "url": "https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/archive/4.4.1.zip"
        },
        "require": {
          "fancyguy/webroot-installer": "1.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "wordpress": "4.4.1",
    "fancyguy/webroot-installer": "1.0.0"
  },
  "extra": {
    "webroot-dir": "./",
    "webroot-package": "wordpress"
  }
}
```

The `vendor` directory and the `composer.lock` still exists.

```
myMBP:testtt erwai$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing fancyguy/webroot-installer (1.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing wordpress (4.4.1)
    Loading from cache

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

myMBP:testtt erwai$ ls
composer.lock       wp-blog-header.php  wp-load.php
index.php       wp-comments-post.php    wp-login.php
license.txt     wp-config-sample.php    wp-mail.php
readme.html     wp-content      wp-settings.php
vendor          wp-cron.php     wp-signup.php
wp-activate.php     wp-includes     wp-trackback.php
wp-admin        wp-links-opml.php   xmlrpc.php

myMBP:testtt erwai$ ls composer.json
ls: composer.json: No such file or directory

myMBP:testtt erwai$ ls composer.lock
composer.lock

myMBP:testtt erwai$ ls vendor
autoload.php    composer
```

---

- OS: OS X 10.11.2
- PHP: 5.5.30
- Composer: 1.0-dev (64b0d721838cdceef679761c5cf69a0d070d14c9)

---

## *EDIT*

I think this may occur while wordpress is being installed.

Since wordpress is installed in the root directory (`"webroot-dir": "./"`), it seems to clean up all the directory.

Is there any idea?

Comment: You should report that as an issue on https://github.com/fancyguy/webroot-installer/issues because it's clearly a bug in that plugin that it is wiping the directory clean when installing.

Comment: The plugin is only returning the custom folder (`$extra['webroot-dir']`). Its Composer, which extracts into this folder (overwriting the content). The plugin could/should be more defensive and warn the user, when the root is targeted.

Comment: The `FileDownloader` and `VcsDownloader` empty the directory before download.  I'm not sure how to gracefully handle a non-empty directory because if there is a previous version already installed it would be expected to be non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

> Since wordpress is installed in the root directory ("webroot-dir": "./"), it seems to clean up all the directory.

Composer extracts the ZIP archive into your folder overwriting its content. 
When Composer finishes, it adds the `composer.lock` file and the Composer Autoloading files (`vendor/autoload.php` and `vendor/composer/*.php`).

---

The intention of this plugin is to install Wordpress into a custom folder (and not into the project folder):

`/home/user/composer-wp-installer-project` with `webroot-dir`: `/var/www/abc.com/wordpress`

So, the idea is to simply not install into the root folder of your project.

Please give this a try:

```
"extra": {
    "webroot-dir": "wordpress",
    "webroot-package": "wordpress"
}
```

This will create a new folder `wordpress` for WP and keeps the "installer" stuff and its `composer.json` in your project folder.

Comment: Another thing to note about the normal installation approach used by composer, the webroot directory shouldn't have install targets under it. e.g. `composer-installers` configured to have `wordpress-plugin` installed in the same directory because an update to the webroot package will remove the packages installed within it.